# Removing polygons from the screen (OpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, geometry, vertex

Assuming the code is:

```
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    //Drawing another object...
```

How would I change the code to erase the object? I know that commenting out glTranslatef() will erase the triangle, but is that the formal way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put glClear at the start of the draw function (draw function is usually in a loop) you can simply choose not to redraw the triangle, drawing like that will leave no reference to your triangle.

Also, glTranslatef() wont remove your triangle, glTranslatef() is just a function to move the current matrix (in your case the matrix with your triangle is being moved into the camera view)

glClear()

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glClear.html

Comment: Thanks, I like that idea. It seems more elegant to clear it instead of just not drawing it.

Comment: @WRU4Android: They way you ask your question and commented I think you may have fallen for the (common) misconception of OpenGL being a kind of scene graph, which it is not. OpenGL is bascially a set of very sophisticated drawing tools: You start with some canvas (the framebuffer) and then paint on it using OpenGL commands. glClear clears the canvas from everything that was on it; then you draw what you want to see. Something changes => You redraw the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to make the triangle go away in subsequent frames, there's no need.  Every frame time you're responsible for redrawing everything.  OpenGL will not remember your triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an `if` around `glBegin`...`glVertex`...`glEnd` would be the most straightforward way.